# AC:R using mute effectively

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the Mute ability supposed to work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/40437/how-is-the-mute-ability-supposed-to-work)

Mute seems to be very powerful in the hands of others, but not me :-(

I feel I'm missing how to use it best - I'm trying to use it like a fast-acting or back-up smoke bomb, but every time I do I end up stunned or dead.

I expect mute to be faster acting, but shorter lived and less visible from a distance. Typically it just doesn't seem to do anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Though, I think it's just mostly broken. I can never get the ability to work consistently. And I feel exactly the same way, powerful for others but not me too.